# Invoke jumpTo method of jQuery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently Im using simplefadeslideshow ( http://www.simplefadeslideshow.com/ ) to do some fade effects.

What I am trying to do, is that upon hovering certain elements on the webpage, is to have the slide change to a certain image.

What I tried was the following:

```
    var slider_1 = jQuery('#slide_show_1').fadeSlideShow({
     width: 285,
     height: 489,
     PlayPauseElement: false, 
     NextElement: false, 
     PrevElement: false, 
     ListElement: false,


    });
```

Which initialises the slider, and works as expected. Then I call:

```
slider_1.jumpTo(2);
```

In a hover event (to fade in the 3rd slide), which returns

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jumpTo'

The script does have a jumpTo() function, so am I calling it wrong? Any help appreciated!

The original script for which im trying to call the method if it helps:

```
jQuery.fn.fadeSlideShow = function(options) {
    return this.each(function(){
        settings = jQuery.extend({
            width: 640, // default width of the slideshow
            height: 480, // default height of the slideshow
            speed: 'slow', // default animation transition speed
            interval: 3000, // default interval between image change
            PlayPauseElement: 'fssPlayPause', // default css id for the play / pause element
            PlayText: 'Play', // default play text
            PauseText: 'Pause', // default pause text
            NextElement: 'fssNext', // default id for next button
            NextElementText: 'Next >', // default text for next button
            PrevElement: 'fssPrev', // default id for prev button
            PrevElementText: '< Prev', // default text for prev button
            ListElement: 'fssList', // default id for image / content controll list
            ListLi: 'fssLi', // default class for li's in the image / content controll 
            ListLiActive: 'fssActive', // default class for active state in the controll list
            addListToId: false, // add the controll list to special id in your code - default false
            allowKeyboardCtrl: true, // allow keyboard controlls left / right / space
            autoplay: true // autoplay the slideshow
        }, options);

        // set style for wrapper element
        jQuery(this).css({
            width: settings.width,
            height: settings.height,
            position: 'relative',
            overflow: 'hidden'
        });

        // set styles for child element
        jQuery('> *',this).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            width: settings.width,
            height: settings.height
        });

        // count number of slides
        var Slides = jQuery('> *', this).length;
        Slides = Slides - 1;
        var ActSlide = Slides;
        // Set jQuery Slide short var
        var jQslide = jQuery('> *', this);
        // save this
        var fssThis = this;
        var intval = false;
        var autoplay = function(){
            intval = setInterval(function(){
                jQslide.eq(ActSlide).fadeOut(settings.speed);

                // if list is on change the active class
                if(settings.ListElement){
                    var setActLi = (Slides - ActSlide) + 1;
                    if(setActLi > Slides){setActLi=0;}
                    jQuery('#'+settings.ListElement+' li').removeClass(settings.ListLiActive);
                    jQuery('#'+settings.ListElement+' li').eq(setActLi).addClass(settings.ListLiActive);
                }

                if(ActSlide <= 0){
                    jQslide.fadeIn(settings.speed);
                    ActSlide = Slides;
                }else{
                    ActSlide = ActSlide - 1;    
                }
            }, settings.interval);

            if(settings.PlayPauseElement){
                jQuery('#'+settings.PlayPauseElement).html(settings.PauseText);
            }
        }

        var stopAutoplay = function(){
            clearInterval(intval);
            intval = false;
            if(settings.PlayPauseElement){
                jQuery('#'+settings.PlayPauseElement).html(settings.PlayText);
            }
        }

        var jumpTo = function(newIndex){
            if(newIndex < 0){newIndex = Slides;}
            else if(newIndex > Slides){newIndex = 0;}
            if( newIndex >= ActSlide ){
                jQuery('> *:lt('+(newIndex+1)+')', fssThis).fadeIn(settings.speed);
            }else if(newIndex <= ActSlide){
                jQuery('> *:gt('+newIndex+')', fssThis).fadeOut(settings.speed);
            }

            // set the active slide
            ActSlide = newIndex;

            if(settings.ListElement){
                // set active
                jQuery('#'+settings.ListElement+' li').removeClass(settings.ListLiActive);
                jQuery('#'+settings.ListElement+' li').eq((Slides-newIndex)).addClass(settings.ListLiActive);
            }
        }

        // if list is on render it
        if(settings.ListElement){
            var i=0;
            var li = '';
            while(i<=Slides){
                if(i==0){
                    li = li+'<li class="'+settings.ListLi+i+' '+settings.ListLiActive+'"><a href="#">'+(i+1)+'<\/a><\/li>';
                }else{
                    li = li+'<li class="'+settings.ListLi+i+'"><a href="#">'+(i+1)+'<\/a><\/li>';
                }
                i++;
            }
            var List = '<ul id="'+settings.ListElement+'">'+li+'<\/ul>';

            // add list to a special id or append after the slideshow
            if(settings.addListToId){
                jQuery('#'+settings.addListToId).append(List);
            }else{
                jQuery(this).after(List);
            }

            jQuery('#'+settings.ListElement+' a').bind('click', function(){
                var index = jQuery('#'+settings.ListElement+' a').index(this);
                stopAutoplay();
                var ReverseIndex = Slides-index;

                jumpTo(ReverseIndex);

                return false;
            });
        }

        if(settings.PlayPauseElement){
            if(!jQuery('#'+settings.PlayPauseElement).css('display')){
                jQuery(this).after('<a href="#" id="'+settings.PlayPauseElement+'"><\/a>');
            }

            if(settings.autoplay){
                jQuery('#'+settings.PlayPauseElement).html(settings.PauseText);
            }else{
                jQuery('#'+settings.PlayPauseElement).html(settings.PlayText);
            }

            jQuery('#'+settings.PlayPauseElement).bind('click', function(){
                if(intval){
                    stopAutoplay();
                }else{
                    autoplay();
                }
                return false;
            });
        }

        if(settings.NextElement){
            if(!jQuery('#'+settings.NextElement).css('display')){
                jQuery(this).after('<a href="#" id="'+settings.NextElement+'">'+settings.NextElementText+'<\/a>');
            }

            jQuery('#'+settings.NextElement).bind('click', function(){
                nextSlide = ActSlide-1;
                stopAutoplay();
                jumpTo(nextSlide);
                return false;
            });
        }

        if(settings.PrevElement){
            if(!jQuery('#'+settings.PrevElement).css('display')){
                jQuery(this).after('<a href="#" id="'+settings.PrevElement+'">'+settings.PrevElementText+'<\/a>');
            }

            jQuery('#'+settings.PrevElement).bind('click', function(){
                prevSlide = ActSlide+1;
                stopAutoplay();
                jumpTo(prevSlide);
                return false;
            });
        }

        if(settings.allowKeyboardCtrl){
            jQuery(document).bind('keydown', function(e){
                if(e.which==39){
                    var nextSlide = ActSlide-1;
                    stopAutoplay();
                    jumpTo(nextSlide);
                }else if(e.which==37){
                    var prevSlide = ActSlide+1;
                    stopAutoplay();
                    jumpTo(prevSlide);
                }else if(e.which==32){
                    if(intval){stopAutoplay();}
                    else{autoplay();}
                    //return false;
                }
            });
        }

        // start autoplay or set it to false
        if(settings.autoplay){autoplay();}else{intval=false;}
    });
};
```

Comment: can you paste the code from which you are calling the `jumpTo` function?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the script.

Comment: i think you misunderstood me. this is the plugin script. i was asking for the code in which **you** are calling the `jumpTo` function.

Comment: jQuery('.fade-out').on("mouseenter", function() {
  
 slider_1.jumpTo(2);  
    
});

Comment: have you declared  `slider_1` as a global variable?

Comment: The  var slider_1 = jQuery('#slide_show_1').fadeSlideShow({ is right after jQuery( document ).ready(function() { so the scope I believe should be correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47653/discussion-between-anurupr-and-rehan-aslam)